# Custom request handler fails at startup

Tags: vespa

I'm writing a custom RequestHandler, extending from ThreadedHttpRequestHandler, and after running `vespa-deploy prepare` and `vespa-deploy activate` the logs are showing a recurring error.

```
[2018-12-27 01:09:42.950] ERROR   : container        Container.com.yahoo.jdisc.core.StandaloneMain
JDisc exiting: Throwable caught:
exception=
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binding configured for non-jdisc request handler my.package.MyRequestHandler
at com.yahoo.container.jdisc.ConfiguredApplication.addHandlerBindings(ConfiguredApplication.java:348)
at com.yahoo.container.jdisc.ConfiguredApplication.intitializeAndActivateContainer(ConfiguredApplication.java:178)
at com.yahoo.container.jdisc.ConfiguredApplication.start(ConfiguredApplication.java:130)
at com.yahoo.jdisc.core.ApplicationLoader.start(ApplicationLoader.java:154)
at com.yahoo.jdisc.core.StandaloneMain.run(StandaloneMain.java:43)
at com.yahoo.jdisc.core.StandaloneMain.main(StandaloneMain.java:34)
```

My services.xml looks like this right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<services version="1.0">
    <container version="1.0">
        <document-api />
        <handler id="my.package.MyRequestHandler" bundle="my-vespa-bundle">
            <binding>http://*/myendpoint</binding>
        </handler>
        <nodes>
            <node hostalias="node1"/>
        </nodes>
    </container>
</services>
```

I've tried tracing as much as I could through the code and it looks like there's a check against a list of configured `Components` where this exception is coming from, but I'm not clear why my Handler is not being picked up by that.

`vespa-deploy prepare` is not showing any additional complaints about the structure of my code or config.

Comment: Can you please attach the `dependencies` section of your pom.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason your handler is not being picked up is that you have embedded the `RequestHandler` class into your own bundle. This will prevent the JDisc framework's class loader from recognizing your handler as a subclass of the `RequestHandler` it uses as reference. You can verify this by running `mvn dependency:tree`. You'll probably see some vespa dependencies in scope `compile`, but they should have been `provided`.

Please take a look at the `dependencies` section of our [sample project](https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/blob/master/basic-search-java/pom.xml#L20) and try to update your `pom.xml` accordingly.